# Accessing system calendar appointments without using system rendered UI

Tags: c#, uwp, appointment

I have been working on including system calendar appointments in my UWP app.

If I use appointments uap capability - `<uap:Capability Name="appointments"/>`, I am able to add events to my system calendar through AddAppointmentsAsync after selecting accept in this popup.

[Add appointment confirmation popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SccJ.png)

But I would like to perform this addition without rendering this confirmation popup (which has some issues as well).

I was able to achieve this by using a restricted capability - `<rescap:Capability Name="appointmentsSystem"/>` (System Level Appointment Access). But it has been specified in documentation that the submission of app with this capability to Microsoft store won't be approved, though my requirement is to get it published.

> We don't recommend that you declare this capability in applications that you submit to the Microsoft Store. In most cases, the use of this capability won't be approved.

Is there any way I can achieve adding appointments to system calendar without using this confirmation popup?

Comment: The popup is mandatory, for good reason-- programs should not be adding things to the user's calendar without their approval. Users do not appreciate that.

Comment: But using the popup has some issues. At times, after giving cancel, on trying to add another event, this popup is rendered blank. Also there is no control for the app to specify to which calendar (among list of calendars in system calendar) this event must be added and it seems like it is chosen randomly (might be based on some criteria) by appointments API itself. Any suggestions to overcome these issues?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue you mentioned in the official sample?https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/bb470280e493a888d98ac367edf3b85f8c053c4f/Samples/Appointments

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT It is reproducible.
Issue : Confirmation popup becomes blank
Pre-condition : System calendar app must be closed.
Steps:
1.Try to add an appointment.
2.When confirmation popup is displayed, give cancel.
3.Try to add an appointment again. Popup will be blank
.

Comment: Also as mentioned earlier, when i have an outlook account/gmail account signed in, in my system calendar, the appointment is added to anyone of the available calendars (one among outlook/gmail/system calendar). But general expectation would be to prompt the user to select the calendar, or atleast, API must support specifying the calendar to which appointment has to be added.

Comment: @Charith, I can't reproduce the same behavior following your steps in the official sample. Could you please tell us your Windows system version?

Comment: Windows 11 Pro 22H2. By the way, do we have any option for allowing users to select calendars.

Comment: "do we have any option for allowing users to select calendars."  Currently there is no such function in UWP.

Comment: Recently uninstalled and reinstalled 'System mail and calendar' application from microsoft store. Since the time I reinstalled it, the option to add 'New event' is disabled and I am not able to add any events. I have verified that all the permissions required for mail and calendar apps are enabled in my system. Still there is no access to add events. Can someone help me fix this problem.  @JunjieZhu-MSFT

Comment: Is there any way to identify the default system calendar among the list of calendars obtained from AppointmentCalendars API?